# Should you use duration_cast<>() or not to measure the difference between two chronos::time_points?

Tags: c++

I cannot find a clear answer on which of the following pieces of code is correct:

The intention is to execute some code in a loop every 'val' ms. As I understood before, you can replace the duration to whatever unit you want (secs, nano, etc.) However, do you need to use duration_cast for it to work accurately ?

1)

```
auto m_intervalFrameCounting = std::chronos::milliseconds(val);

auto now = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto diff = now - m_lastTimeFramesCounted;
if (diff > m_intervalFrameCounting) {
    m_lastTimeFramesCounted = high_resolution_clock::now();
    //do something
}
```

or:
2)

```
auto m_intervalFrameCounting = std::chronos::milliseconds(val);

auto now = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto diff = now - m_lastTimeFramesCounted;
if (std::chronos::duration_cast<milliseconds>(diff) > m_intervalFrameCounting) {
    m_lastTimeFramesCounted = high_resolution_clock::now();
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Not when doing something like that. `duration_cast` is mostly used to convert a duration to the format you want to display.

Comment: You really should consult the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_arith4).  As you can see: Converts the two durations to their common type and creates a duration whose tick count is the rhs number of ticks subtracted from the lhs number of ticks after conversion.

Comment: To the down voter:  This is a decent question (upvoted).  No other programming time system that I'm aware of will allow heterogeneous time units comparisons without introducing errors (at least compile-time, or worse yet run-time).  Newcomers to `<chrono>` from other time-handling libraries (in any language) have reason to be suspicious and cautious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`duration_cast` is for casting a duration to a type which would make it lose precision. milliseconds to seconds, for example. While seconds to milliseconds is implicitly allowed. There's no reason for the #2 method, what were you hoping that to achieve? #1 is what you're after.

Comment: Upvoted.  Additional information:  `<chrono>` comparisons (equality or relational) are **always exact**, with no casts needed, no matter what crazy different units you may have on either side of the comparison operator.  As a more general rule:  if you code it with `<chrono>`, and it doesn't contain use of type safety escape hatches like `.count()` or `.time_since_epoch()`, then if it compiles, chances are very, very good that the code is correct.  It is hard to accidentally inject run time errors into `<chrono>` code.

Comment: @David: I just wanted it to work as expected. I am trying to simulate the rate that some sensors feed data frames to a system I am debugging. The requirement was to get 30 frames per sensor (8) so 240fps. The 1) method was not reaching the desired frame rate so I was wondering if I was misusing <chronos>. I suspect something else was causing the drop in frames. At least now I know it wasn't my use of <chronos>